# file upload fails after jquery preventDefault

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to do a file upload with JSP / JQuery but I have to make a few Ajax calls before submission.

However, after the Ajax calls are made and the form is submitted the form fields are all empty on the server side?

If I don't call e.preventDefault() then it all works but I need to make Ajax calls pre-submission!

Thanks

```
CLIENT SIDE:

<form method="post" action="accept.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  <input type="file" name="thefile" id="thefile"/>
  <input type="submit" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" value="Upload File"/>
  ...
</form>

$("form").on("submit", function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form being submitted for now

    // make a few ajax calls
    ...

    // submit the form in ajax success callback
    $("form").unbind("submit");
    $("form").submit();
}

SERVER SIDE:

boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
servletFileUpload.setFileSizeMax(Long.valueOf(maxUploadFileSize));
servletFileUpload.setProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener());
FileItemIterator fileItemIterator = servletFileUpload.getItemIterator(request);

if(isMultipart)
{
    while(fileItemIterator.hasNext())  <--- empty?
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just using a `input type='button'` element? You wouldn't have to prevent the submit part and still be able to call `$("form").submit();` at the end. I'm not sure if it fixes your problem though.

Comment: Same issue occurs if I submit the form after binding a function to `input type='button'`. The file or other input fields are not available on the server side. It seems that any interference breaks the file upload submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a JQuery statement in one of the Ajax calls that disabled the file input field. When this was removed the file became available again on the server side. So disabling the file input field causes it to become unavailable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) 
{
    // make a few ajax calls
    ...

    // finally submit
    $("form").unbind("submit");
    $("form").submit();
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form being submitted for now
}
```

`e.preventDefault();` send return false may issue with ajax